# OS X: Determining which command runs scripts with a particular extension

Tags: macos, shell, file-extension

I'm writing a program for macOS that shall be able to execute "UNIX scripts" of various types (perl, python etc.), using them for text filtering through stdin -> script -> stdout.

I like to design it so that the user only has to specify the path to the script, without having to specify which command the script needs.

For instance:

- `.pl` scripts need `perl`
- `.py` scripts need `python`
- `.sh` scripts need `sh`

But there may be more, and some users may even install other tools I could not predict. So, I want to avoid having hard code the mapping between extension and command.

I wonder if OS X or BSD has some provision for this kind of need. Is there a config file or a tool I can use that will tell me:

- Is this a script?
- Which command does the script need to run it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) - and you don't even need care about the extensions...

Comment: Look at the man page for "file".  It should be possible to parse its output.

Comment: @PhillipMills Nope - `file` does not provide a standardized format that I could parse with my program. And it does not even tell me which command it uses.

Comment: @jm666 That, sadly, does not work reliably. For instance, I have scripts (which came with BBEdit, whose Text Filters I try to use) that contain `#!/usr/local/bin/python`. However, my Mac has no python cmd at that path, it's at `/usr/bin/python`. At least, all scripts I looked at so far supply such a line, so I could still try to parse that and correct the path if necessary.

Comment: The WP article actually discusses the issues, so I guess I'll try to work something out along those guidelines. I had expected, though, to find a central database for extension-to-interpreter mapping.

Comment: `/usr/bin/env python` - simply, do not try reinvent the wheel again... Here is a standardized way executing scripts - so use it ;)

Comment: I think you do not understand the premise here. The scripts are supplied by the user, and I have to execute them. If the user takes a script from somewhere, e.g. BBEdit, where they work, and if I fail to run them, he will not end up coming here listening to your helpful guidance. The user is not a unix geek in this case. I have to make sure I can execute the scripts as they work with other tools such as BBEdit. Also, some ruby scripts contain `#!/usr/bin/env ruby18` - but there is no "ruby18" at all, but "ruby" works. Will now do shebang, and if it fails, fallback to hard-coded mapping by ext.

Comment: If the user supplying the script, you're staying on very thin layer of ice... What if it needs perl >= 5.24? (defined by the perl's `use` statement) etc. Especially the `bash` is problematic, because OS X has only bash 3.2 (really archaic version) and many bash scripts needs 4.0+. (e.g. associative arrays). You simply **can't** determine by yourself, how some third-party author (e.g.not you, nor the "nongeek user") designed the script.  So, especially it **will not** help executing some interpreters by the "extensions". That's all my "guidance".. :)